Why is PromQL so wrong about basic math?
I am trying to write an alert based on runaway thread growth and while playing around with PromQL I found the numbers don't add up at all.
For confidentiality I can't write the exact metrics I was using, so I will use placeholders, but it shouldn't matter because this applies to any gauge metric.
First I tried getting the thread growth rate using idelta idelta(metric[$__range]), which should give me the change between each data point, but apparently 4 - 3 = 2?

(ignore the normalized, I forgot the change the label)
I then tried doing it manually, by doing metric - metric offset 15s, where 15s is our sampling interval. This was working fine, and I compared it with the idelta function and I was astonished to find out it's more often wrong than it is correct

(Yellow line is true, verified manually; blue line is idelta)
Whatever I thought, at least I have the true metric I wanted. I then proceeded to sum it over time to get the rolling sum of added threads over 1min (4 data points) sum_over_time((metric - metric offset 15s) [1m:]). Come to find out, it's utter nonsense too!

I guess 1 + 0 + 6 + (-2) = -2 and (-1) + (-18) + (-2) + 2 = -2. It doesn't even matter if there's some timing boundary error, because if I include an extra one or two points on either side, the math doesn't work out.
Can someone explain why this happens? Am I just using it completely wrong or something?

Let's start with sum_over_time: it doesn't get what you want (probably) because you misunderstood how subquery works. If you omit resolution part it's substituted by global evaluation interval (of Prometheus). By default it is 1m. In your described case you need [1m:15s]. But I'm not sure why you'd do it in such a convoluted way. If your scrape interval is 15s then sum_over_time((metric - metric offset 15s) [1m:15s]) is equivalent to metric - metric offset 1m

Regarding idelta: I'm not 100% sure here, but description for delta() mentions that it "is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if the sample values are all integers". Based on the same premise, I wouldn't be surprised that internally something more trickier is happening than simple subtraction.

If I were in your position, I'd evaluate both idelta and offset queries in Prometheus directly (to exclude Grafana from equation), and if results are the same, open ticket in Prometheus' repo (of course checking beforehand that same or very similar ticket is not open yet)

Here's a small trick for how to put both queries on the same graph in Prometheus' web console: label_replace(idelta(metric[$__range]),"method","idelta","","") or label_replace(metric - metric offset 15s, "method","offset","","")
